# How can I customize a Core Plot graph to mimic this style?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I would like to draw a line graph in the same style as the one posted in [this Core Plot issue](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=108).

Is there a tutorial out there on how to create a graph like this in Core Plot?

Comment: The link you gave is not working please correct it.

Comment: still not a valid link. keep trying.

Comment: Try just posting a link to the issue rather than directly to the attachment.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=108

Comment: You can refer this question. The answers and links given in this post(Bar Graph as well as Line and Pie) can help you out. [Graphs in iOS App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164523/bar-graphs-in-ios-app) Good luck.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below links this will help you.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application

http://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/PlotExamples

Comment: Answers that just link to other content are not Answers in the SO universe. What if the links change? Please summarise the ideas or examples from the links and cite where the information came from. The idea is to make SO Answers standalone.

Comment: all tutorial are good but best way to learn core plot are those examples present in the core plot install zip