# how to create a core plot in ios

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot

i'm new in doing graph in iphone. anyone can recommend me any sample coding or tutorial on doing core plot ? it will be good if u can recommend me other graph api :)

i have a look on the scatter plot demo from core-plot, which is what i wanted to do, but i do not know how to change it to the diagram below. is it difficult to do it ?

i'm looking to do something like this.

[image]

Any comment is appreciated thanks

DK

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I customize a Core Plot graph to mimic this style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420717/how-can-i-customize-a-core-plot-graph-to-mimic-this-style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out [google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_playground.html)
The link I have provided takes you to the google charts "live chart playground" page with which you can customize your chart however you want using the parameters available.

Once you customize the chart according to the way you want, you will have to copy the URL created above the chart and use it in your app.

To use the link in your chart, you will have to create a web view in your app and then call this url to show the graph in the web view.. this is possible by the following code

```
[yourWebView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourGraphURLString]]];
```

where yourWebView would be your web view and yourGraphURLString would be the URL you get from google charts..

Comment: hi learner,

Thanks for the reply, this is what i ultimately wanted to do. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/418769/Picture1.png
i need the graph on top of a tableview...is it possible for google graph ? sorry i'm a newbie in iOS programming :)

Comment: yes.. it is definitely possible to do that.. you need to use the line chart option on google charts.. if you play with google charts ( playground) for 1 hour, you will know what I mean...

Comment: Thanks learner,
i need to do it off line, i'm currently using powerplot for my graph....hope all went well :)

cheers