# Fancy looking charts in iOS 5? (Maybe skin Core Plot?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

ad mentioned in the title I'm looking for a nice way for some nice looking bar graphs in iOS.
I've already read this post:
[Bar Graphs in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164523/bar-graphs-in-ios-app)
Core Plot seems to be first choice for most devs.

But regarding the given screenshots it's not that "Web 2.0"-like look which I'd like to realize.

So - does anybody know a lib which looks really nice or way to custom-skin Core Plot?

The possibility to animate the graph for changing values would be perfect though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just about everything in a Core Plot bar graph is customizable, from border color to line width to fill color (or gradient).  The screenshots on the project site are merely some defaults that are used in the sample applications that come with the framework.

If you look at the [long list of applications that use Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/AppsUsingCorePlot), you can see many different styles of graphs, including some different takes on bar charts.

There are a few stock themes, which can be used to create a default graph look using code like the following:

```
// Create barChart from theme
barChart = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
[barChart applyTheme:theme];
```

Built-in themes currently include `kCPTDarkGradientTheme`, `kCPTPlainBlackTheme`, `kCPTPlainWhiteTheme`, `kCPTSlateTheme`, and `kCPTStocksTheme`, but you can create your own or use these as a starting point to customize your bar chart however you like.

If you can't figure out how to do a particular style of bar chart using Core Plot, you can ask about that on [the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss) or in a focused question here.

Comment: So....I downloaded this with the hopes of following your advice..but i'm receiving all sorts of errors pertaining to file paths and such.  I can't even get the example applications to run.

I'm on XCode 4.2 and trying to build an iOS 5 app...any other help would be awesome.

Comment: @d2burke - Make sure you follow the instructions from the project wiki for incorporation of this within your application: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications . The "Dependent Project Install" section is what you should use, and I've found those instructions to work without a problem for the last few projects I've started with this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several commercial tools for iOS charting, some of which look quite fancy!

- [ShinobiControls](http://www.shinobicontrols.com) - which has many interactive features as shown [in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxK1oE0vXog).
- [www.threedgraphics.com](http://www.threedgraphics.com)
- [iPhone Charting Library for iPhone Objective-C](http://www.keepedge.com/products/iphone_charting/)

***Full Disclosure** - I work for Scott Logic, which is the parent company of ShinobiControls*