# How to create a simple graph just showing two lines in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to create a simple graph which will get the values and shows the graph like below image shown

[image: graph showing the color lines]

I have also create other graphs using pie chart class but how to make this simple graph to show two line with like this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bar Graphs in iOS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164523/bar-graphs-in-ios-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Bar Graphs in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164523/bar-graphs-in-ios-app/5164573#5164573) this thread.
On the provided link there are a lot of frameworks which you can use. For drawing simple graphs there are simpler frameworks than CorePlot.

Comment: i want to use ecgraph but when i add this in method in simple view controller it gives error i am using in this way

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bar (or column) chart for iPhone using [SciChart](http://www.scichart.com).

There is an example showing Objective-C and Swift code] to generate a column chart here: https://www.scichart.com/example/ios-column-chart-demo/

[image]

There's a quick tutorial on how to add series to an [iOS/iPhone/iPad chart here](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/ios/v2.x/Tutorial%2003%20-%20Adding%20Series%20to%20a%20Chart.html), as well as source code for the tutorial on [github](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.iOS.Examples).

*Disclosure: I am the tech lead of the SciChart project*

Answer (score 1):

A commonly used Cocoa "native" charting library is [Core Plot.](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/). Whilst I've yet to personally use it, it seems to be [quite popular](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/AppsUsingCorePlot) and is under active development.

or

You can check out the [PowerPlot library](http://powerplot.nua-schroers.de/). It is a powerful choice for native charts on iOS, here are a two sample bar graphs:

The Images Like

[image]
[image]

Using PowerPlot, the code needed to generate these two graphs is available [here (upper chart)](http://powerplot.nua-schroers.de/examples/fedelect.html) and [here (lower chart)](http://powerplot.nua-schroers.de/examples/webtraffic.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [Quartz-2d Tutorial](http://buildmobile.com/creating-a-graph-with-quartz-2d-part-2/#fbid=o0fDk6vTjVC).