# Create BarChart application in ios

Tags: ios, bar-chart

Hi I want to create bar chart application with slider control in ios. once my slider is changed my chart also changed and their datas also changed. I am new for this field. I dont know how and where to start in this application. If anybody knows please guide me or any other links send me. Advance in thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways of achieving this.

You can use API's such as Core Plot to achieve your requirement. At the same time you can use Core Graphics & quartz Core to achieve it.

You should also check this out [Bar Graphs in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164523/bar-graphs-in-ios-app)

Comment: Thanks footyapps27: Can you provide me more information on Graphs except using CorePlot ? and how to implementing slider control in the graph.

Comment: sure!!

I would advise you to start with Core Graphics & Quartz Core if you do not want to use Core Plot.

Comment: Thanks again, Is it possible with out use core plot could create bar graph with slider control. How? any other options using Core Graphics & Quartz Core to make a graph.

Comment: there are third party API's that you can use, such as:

code.google.com/p/s7graphview
sebkade.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/basic-graph-class-for-iphone

For slider i guess you need to check them out.

Comment: sorry to say this, I go to this link sebkade.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/basic-graph-class-for-iphone. I try to download source code but page not found error is occur, now how i get this? any other possibilities?

Comment: Hey it seems that the host has removed the file. You can search for ECGraph components in google and try that out.

Answer (score 0):

i've made a hack 
Make custom uiview for each bar accord to your input values.
set frame of each uiview(bar) according to input values.
there is no need of corePlot files if u want simple bar graph[image: graph using uiview for each bar]

[image: graph made by custom uiview]